# wymeditor cannot save inserted iframe

Tags: wysiwyg, wymeditor

WymEditor (http://wymeditor.org) always deletes inserted iframe to its content. So i cannot add vimeo player block to my page.

How can I avoid it?

Regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [May 31, 2011](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/commit/05d2a566856470f91c99f25e56d3f30c24d6d44b), the WYMeditor [Embed Plugin](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/tree/master/src/wymeditor/plugins/embed) supports iframe embedding. To include this support, simply include the embed plugin script in your HTML. Eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/wymeditor/plugins/embed/jquery.wymeditor.embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've submitted a patch to address this issue so it is up to them to accept it. http://j.mp/fo4QOi