# Embed doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, wymeditor

Here's how javascript includes look like on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/wymeditor/jquery.wymeditor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/wymeditor/plugins/embed/jquery.wymeditor.embed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/admin_textarea.js"></script>
```

The problem is that when I save the content within the iframe, it is removed.
**UPDATE**
Here is the content of `admin_textarea.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('head', document).append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/js/wymeditor/skins/minimal/skin.css" />');
    $('head', document).append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/js/wymeditor/skins/minimal/skin.js" />');
    $("textarea").wymeditor({
        updateSelector: "input:submit",
        updateEvent:    "click",
        lang: 'ru'
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess this is your answer then:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634616/wymeditor-cannot-save-inserted-iframe

Comment: Actually I think I have this plugin included. Check out third row.

Comment: Are you sure all scripts load?

Comment: Yeah, I can open them using these urls

Comment: What is in admin_textarea.js? And when you say "content within the iframe," I'm assuming you're talking about within the body of the editor iframe. When you say "save the content", are you referring to submitting the form in which the textarea you're replacing lives? What do you mean "removed"? As in, that content isn't correctly POST'd to your server? Do you have the class `wymupdate` on your submit/save button?

Comment: @WesWinham, I've added content of admin_textarea.js file to question. About iframe, I mean that when I push submit button all other content of textarea is saved but iframe (youtube video iframe) is not. More than that, when I push the button I see the line with iframe removed first, this happens even before http request is sended and page is refreshed.

Comment: This is unrelated, but you're linking the skin.js as a stylesheet instead of a script. You probably haven't noticed it because, historically, WYMeditor goes out and loads your skin javascript for you, but that's going to change in WYMeditor 1.0.

As far as the iframe being stripped from the content, that either means that your jquery.wymeditor.embed.js plugin is old or it isn't actually being loaded (404). Are you using the latest version of the plugin? https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/blob/master/src/wymeditor/plugins/embed/jquery.wymeditor.embed.js

Comment: @WesWinham thanks. I use WYMEditor 0.5 and plugin was already there. The file definitely loads and there are no errors in js console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embed plugin doesn't support iframes for versions prior to [version 1.0.0a1](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/releases/tag/v1.0.0a1). See the [1.0.0b1 changelog](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100b1-beta-1) for details. You'll need to upgrade the version of your embed plugin.

That support was added with [this commit](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/commit/fb3a77e4b7c5834173c7e1a2379629f2a83ee523), if you'd like to patch your version. Otherwise, you should be able to just replace your file with the [latest version](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/blob/master/src/wymeditor/plugins/embed/jquery.wymeditor.embed.js).